# Error: Bitwise binary operator for BYTES requires equal length of the inputs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm unable to run bit operations like:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT b'123' &  b'71278234'
```

Error is:

> Error: Bitwise binary operator for BYTES requires equal length of the inputs. Got 3 bytes on the left hand side and 8 bytes on the right hand side.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can `RPAD()` your bytes to make them the same size. Even better, encapsulate this into a SQL UDF:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION TolerantBitwiseAnd(x BYTES, y BYTES) AS (
 RPAD(x, GREATEST(LENGTH(x), LENGTH(y))) & RPAD(y, GREATEST(LENGTH(x), LENGTH(y)))
);

SELECT TolerantBitwiseAnd(b'123', b'71278234');
```